# Displaying fractions nicely

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I'd like the following to look nicer:

```
$\frac{1 - \left(\frac{r-3}{r-1}  \right)^{k-(p+q)+1}}{1 - \left(\frac{r-3}{r-1}  \right)}$
```

As of now, the horizontal line is way too long.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: There is the `\dfrac` command, but I can't remember in which package it can be found.

Comment: @ChristianH. `amsmath`.

Comment: If the horizontal line does not include the exponent, then I'd be unsure whether the exponent applies to the whole fraction.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the command `\mathrlap` from the `mathtools` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Displaystyle version

\[\dfrac{1 - \left(\dfrac{r-3}{r-1}  \right)^{\mathrlap{k-(p+q)+1}}}{1 - \left(\dfrac{r-3}{r-1}  \right)}\]

\bigskip

Here is the inline version $\frac{1 - \left(\frac{r-3}{r-1}  \right)^{\mathrlap{k-(p+q)+1}}}{1 - \left(\frac{r-3}{r-1}  \right)}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could certainly use a trick like this:

`${\frac{1 - \left(\frac{r-3}{r-1}  \right)}{1 - \left(\frac{r-3}{r-1}  \right)}}^{\mbox{\tiny $k-(p+q)+1$}}$`

Comment: +1, but you can tweak it even better by adding `\!\!` at the beginning of the tiny mbox, as `^{\mbox{\tiny $\!\!k-(p+q)+1$}}`